# Java NIO - Accumulation of messages

Tags: java, server, client, nio

I'm writing a Java application that uses NIO sockets. 
It consists of 3 servers and a set of clients. A client can communicate with a server, and a server can communicate with a client and the other servers.

Servers to servers and clients to servers sends `Message`s that are serialize to a `byte[]` array. The first byte of each `Message` contains the size of the message and naturally it is guaranteed that each message does not contain more than `127 (2^8 -1)` bytes. 
You can think of the sending of messages of the servers and the clients as operating in a loop:

```
Message msg = new Message()
while (true) {
    sendMessage(msg, server or client)
    receiveMessage()
}
```

Then, the  implementation utilizes `ByteBuffer`. Naturally, as in any Java NIO implementation, each server does `selector.select()` and then retrieves the `SelectionKey`s to see if `read`ing (calling `handleRead()` method), `write`ing (calling `handleWrite()`), or `accept`ing (calling `handleAccept()`) needs to be handled. All the `handleXX` methods take a finite number of steps and do not block waiting for anything else.

When retrieving the data (`handleRead()`) for a specific `key`, I just store the data in a specific map `Map<SelectionKey, List<byte[]>> readDataForKey;` Then I traverse the list and extract all the messages that have been received.

However, I noticed that sometimes when entering `handleRead` for some `key` there are thousands of messages waiting to be processed. I cannot figure out why this would be the case?
I would expect `handleRead` to see a couple of messages and that would be it.

The fact that some times thousand of messages get accumulated before they are being processed. What does that mean? Does it mean that my `handleRead` or `handleWrite` or some other part of the NIO implementation takes too long and the underlying buffers get full? Does it mean that once in a while I get a GC even (for ~10ms) and in the meantime the buffers get full? Does it mean that I have code that is perhaps slow in `handleRead` and therefore the messages get accumulated?

Is it normal for so many messages to accumulate?

Comment: It means your processing is too slow.

Comment: I'll look into that. Thanks. 
Would it also be possible that the accumulation occurs due to the size of the `ByteBuffer` I used in regards to the channels? For example, if the buffers are too big, would this make Java fill them up with more messages before calling the handlers?

Comment: Are you running into *problems* because these messages are accumulating (e.g. crashes, dropped messages, etc.) or simply trying to understand the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: My performance problem is that the system's throughput is pretty low. But I also cannot see why so many messages would accumulate.

Comment: 1.  do you update the map(bookkeeping) properly after the message is consumed?

2.  Emitting the metrics on reading count, write count, read processing latency, write processing latency, map size.  Will you help pinpoint where the problem is

3.  We should check for mem-leaks(unintentional).  If you can give the sample code(no business logic) of write/read; it'll help

Answer (score 1):

**Your messages are very small. So send and receive buffers can contain a lot of messages**. If you do not explicitely specify the size of send and receive buffers the TCP stack will do its best to optimize the sizes for efficient transmission over your network. While default sizes for most Linux distributions are around 128 KB maximal sizes may be multiple megabytes (e.g. on networks with very high latency). **Therefore a single handleRead can easily see hundreds or thousands of messages**. TCP tries to use the bandwith of your network as good as possible. Seeing a lot of messages in the receive buffer does not automatically mean that your receiver is overloaded. TCP even avoids that your receiver gets overloaded. The only way to measure, whether your system is "overloaded" is to measure the time it takes to send messages (e.g. queue your messages before they are sent and measure its size)

There are cases where it makes sense to optimize buffer sizes manually (e.g. networks with very high latency) but most of the time the TCP stack does a good job here. There are also very rare cases where it makes sense to disable Nagle's algorithm (e.g. Telnet and SSH) to minimize reaction time on user input, but most of the time, there is absolutely no need for manual intervention. Let TCP do its job, which is optimizing for efficient transmission and avoiding that a receiver gets overloaded.

Comment: Even a buffer of 64KB on OS level could contain many of your messages before any data is sent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I disabled Nagle's algorithm .. you think it would make sense to change the buffers with the `SO_SNDBUF`?

Comment: I would neither suggest to disable Nagle's argorithm nor to change send buffer size. Your receiver is simply overloaded. And that's the point where you should focus on.
TCP simply avoids  that your overloaded receiver causes a silly window syndrome /  inefficient transmations. While this explains, why messages are sent in bulk (due to their small size) its definitely not the point where you should try to optimize.

(see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silly_window_syndrome).

Comment: Another reason for bulked messages could also be that your sender is overloaded. In this case disabling Nagle's algorithm could help, but using multiple connections would definitely be a better option.

Comment: I've edited my answer since the hint with the flusing was more than misleading. Hope the update clarifies things.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I'll add my comment here...

Does the problem happens with 
 1. single client and single server? 2 server only (i.e. no clients)?

2. Single server with multiple clients?
3. Regarding:

> Does it mean that my handleRead or handleWrite or some other part of the NIO implementation takes too long

You can add some logs to measure the time you spend there (or if you want to go further you could use MAT or VisualVM, which might also hint if you are being delayed due to GC)